# Algebraic boolean equation; final step to proving !((!A.B)+(B.!C)) = !B+(A.C)

Tags: boolean, expression

note: sorry for the poor title, it's extremely difficult making one that "Accurately describes your question" that is not similar to other titles.

I'm fairly new to this and my teacher left us with this tough question to try do at home:

```
> !((!A.B)+(B.!C))
```

I already did most of the work:

```
(A.B)+(A.C)+(B.C)
```

What i want to know is, what are the next steps to simplifying this algebraic Boolean expression into

```
!B+(A.C)
```

Why does B become !B? And which is the redundant part of the expression?

edit: forgot to mention, i'm using De Morgan's Theorem to work this out.

Comment: How did you get to `(A.B)+(A.C)+(B.C)`?

Comment: maybe i did that wrong... as i said, i'm new to this.

Comment: oh yeah, i used De morgan's theorem (sorry for not mentioning)

Comment: once i got to A.B + A.C + B.B + B.C, i thought that B.B is redundant so i got rid of it, leaving me with (A.B)+(A.C)+(B.C)

Comment: `B . B` is equivalent to `B`, you can't just drop it. I suggest you start with looking at the distrubtivity of . over + i.e. `(x . y) + (x . z) = x . (y + z)`.